# Codeigniter redirect solution

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect

Trying to get

```
www.example.com/home
```

to go directly to

```
www.example.com/
```

What I've tried:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /samle/%1/$1 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

but its website rotating always .

```
Redirect 301 /home http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: `redirect()` without `params` will do

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is that you want the index function in your "home" controller to be the default homepage, you can set that in routes.php under the route['default_controller'] parameter. That way you don't need to worry about the redirect at all. If you want to remove /home anytime it's typed in, you can use a mod-rewrite like you do to remove index.php from the uri. Check out the docs for more info http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html